# I got OS Error while extraction of relations in window but it works in dos

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I am doing a small project which is based on ontology and knowledge graph. Right now am doing extracting triples from unstructured text(any text) so from this text I have to extract subject predicate and object then I suppose to draw the knowledge graph okay but the thing is that am new to this field and don't know how to extract triples using python and StanFordCoreNLP. I already tried the spacy to extract triples but whenever i use text file then **read_csv** function doesn't take that text.

Then i crossed with one github link which is i mentioned here only see this [triple-extraction](https://github.com/rutvik5/knowledge-graph)
but the thing is that this code is compatible with dos only but i have a windows operating system but then after that i have tried my best to extract triples but i have encountered with one error which is OS Error.

see this error that i got in my terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\knowledge-graph\relation_extractor.py", line 33, in <module>
    Stanford_Relation_Extractor()
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\knowledge-graph\relation_extractor.py", line 24, in Stanford_Relation_Extractor
    p = subprocess.Popen([current_directory + '\\stanford-openie\\process_large_corpus.sh',f,f + '-out.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "F:\MyProjectOntology\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "F:\MyProjectOntology\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

See the code that I am working with but this is compatible with dos so how can I convert this for windows

```
import os
import subprocess
import glob
import pandas as pd

def Stanford_Relation_Extractor():

    
    print('Relation Extraction Started')

    for f in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "\data\output\kg\*.txt"):        
        print("Extracting relations for " + f.split("\\")[-1])
        print(f)
        path2 = f.split('\\')[-1]
        print(path2)
        print(os.getcwd() + '\\stanford-openie\\')

        current_directory = os.getcwd()
        path1 = current_directory + '\\stanford-openie\\process_large_corpus.sh'

        print(current_directory)
        os.chdir(current_directory + '\\stanford-openie')

        p = subprocess.Popen([current_directory + '\\stanford-openie\\process_large_corpus.sh',f,f + '-out.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        output, err = p.communicate()
   

    print('Relation Extraction Completed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Stanford_Relation_Extractor()
```

If someone knows how to resolve this or has any knowledge about this then do let me know.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I got `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` error once only. This occurred when I tried to run the code with 64-bit Python version inside a virtual environment that was created with 32-bit Python version. Check if you are using the right interpretor/virtual environment.

Comment: after adding shell=True ... Error was resolved but if someone knows how to extract entities using python then tell me ASAP!